# Can't change font family in boostrap "well" component

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a well boostrap component containing some text

```
 <div class="well well-sm" id="well_job">

                            <p>
                               <h5><%= "#{job.job_description}" %></h5>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                              <h6><%= "#{job.from_date} -" %></h6><h6><%= "#{job.to_date}" %></h6>
                            </p>
                    </div>
```

when I try to select it by one of its classes to change the font family it doesn't change(I tried to select it by .well-sm but nothing changes as well):

```
    .well{
      font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
}
```

How can I select the well and change the font-size to its inside text?

Comment: Try to add a !important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your syntax is incorrect as you cannot place a header tag inside a paragraph tag. The following syntax

```
<p>
  <h1>Some Header</h1>
</p>
```

will be interpreted by the browsers as

```
<p></p>
   <h1>Some Header</h1>
</p>
```

and you will end up having an unexpected `</p>` end tag. Validating your html will lead to this error:

> No **p** element in scope but a **p** end tag seen.

Back to your question, in case of using header tags you also need to specify a style targeting that specific header tag.

```
.well {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.well h5 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: thanks my friend...I already corrected what you pointed out.....Now, regarding the question, I have 7 wells and I want to use the same font in all of them. Can't I just define a generic rule with  .well{  font-family: "font-name"  }  ?? I tried to do that with the google font I described earlier but it's not changing the font, and the font is working properly on other elements...

Comment: @JAF Yes you can do that. You just need to make sure that the font you use is available or explicitly import it.

Comment: Thanks....The problem was that I had a well with nested <p></p>....If I defined only .well {} it only changed the text inside the well but outside those p tags..... I had to define an extra rule   .well p {    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive; }  and THEN the fonts changed....I thought you could be less specific, but since I'm using a template from other guy this is neccesary to override that rule right?....If I would have started from scratch then I guess I could have defined just the .well{ } rule without having to define that 2nd.....did I get it right??

Comment: @JAF I believe that your issue is related to css specificity. It might be that in your css code you have a p{ font-family:...;} declaration that has a higher specificity than .well{font-family:...;} overwriting your well font declaration. See example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMrpWj)

Answer (score 0):

Have you import the font into the tag `<head>`?

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then for change the font size:

```
.well{
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
}
.well p h5{
    font-size:30px;
}
.well p h6{
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: I did my friend, and the font is working.....But when I apply the rule 

.well{
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;

}

it doesn't change the text, and the font is working cause I could apply it to the headers outside the wells